# ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFromString slows down in long running application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have an application that essentially shows a slide show of images from a file.  The loading of the images slows down over time.  Putting in some timing code, I've identified the slowing line of code as the ConvertFromString line below:

```
var imgSrcConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
imgSrc = (ImageSource) imgSrcConverter.ConvertFromString(imgFilePath);
```

Over the course if 15 hours, the execution of this line went from taking ~70ms to >400ms.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why this would happen and what can be done to prevent and/or improve the situation?

Comment: Are you holding the imgSrc in memory perpetually?  Check for memory leaks.

Comment: Is this in a loop.  Can you get reference and just hold it.  If not make sure the old ImageSourceConverter is getting disposed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you load the images into memory on startup, and then just cycle through them?